# Fatal Exception while executing doInBackground() method in android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to fetch some data from the yahoo weather api, but it shows me a Fatal exception in doBackGround(). First Time it will run properly but the second time I run, it shows me this error. I'm trying this code and shows error in this method method is

```
  String url1 = src.substring(1, src.length() - 2);
```

Using code is :

```
package com.gird.completeontologyproject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WeatherSHow extends Activity {
    ImageView icon1 = null;
    TextView date = null, temp = null, condition = null, humidity = null,
            wind = null;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    String temperature = null, date1 = null, condition1 = null,
            humidity1 = null, wind1 = null, link = null;
    ArrayList<String> weather=null;
    Bitmap icon = null;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        setContentView(R.layout.weather_pref);
        icon1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
        date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateText);
        temp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempText);
        condition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.conditionText);
        humidity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humidityText);
        wind = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.windText);

        new RetriveWeatherTask().execute();
    }

    class RetriveWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(WeatherSHow.this);
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String Result = "";
            String uri = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2295415&u=c;";
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localcontext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
            try {
                HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httpget,
                        localcontext);
                HttpEntity entity = httpresponse.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    InputStream inputstream = entity.getContent();
                    Reader resder = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
                    BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(resder);
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String ReadLine = null;
                    while ((ReadLine = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(ReadLine + "\n");
                    }

                    Result = stringBuilder.toString();
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            Document docu = null;
            DocumentBuilder parse1 = null;
            DocumentBuilderFactory docuFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            try {
                parse1 = docuFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                docu = parse1
                        .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(Result.getBytes()));
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException ed) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ed.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            Node tempretureNode = docu.getElementsByTagName(
                    "yweather:condition").item(0);
            temperature = tempretureNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("temp")
                    .getNodeValue().toString();

            Node TempratureUnit = docu.getElementsByTagName("yweather:units")
                    .item(0);
            temperature = temperature
                    + " "
                    + TempratureUnit.getAttributes()
                            .getNamedItem("temperature").getNodeValue()
                            .toString();

            Node dateNode = docu.getElementsByTagName("yweather:forecast")
                    .item(0);
            date1 = dateNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("date")
                    .getNodeValue().toString();

            Node conditionNode = docu
                    .getElementsByTagName("yweather:condition").item(0);
            condition1 = conditionNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("text")
                    .getNodeValue().toString();

            Node humidityNode = docu
                    .getElementsByTagName("yweather:atmosphere").item(0);
            humidity1 = humidityNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("humidity")
                    .getNodeValue().toString();

            Node windNode = docu.getElementsByTagName("yweather:wind").item(0);
            wind1 = windNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("speed")
                    .getNodeValue().toString();

            Node windUnits = docu.getElementsByTagName("yweather:units")
                    .item(0);
            wind1 = wind1
                    + " "
                    + windUnits.getAttributes().getNamedItem("speed")
                            .getNodeValue().toString();

            String desc = docu.getElementsByTagName("item").item(0)
                    .getChildNodes().item(13).getTextContent().toString();
            StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(desc, "<=>");
            String src = str.nextToken();
//Exception In this Method.
            String url1 = src.substring(1, src.length() - 2);
            Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile("(.+?)<br />");
            Matcher matcher = TAG_REGEX.matcher(desc);
            weather=new ArrayList<String>();
            while (matcher.find()) {
                weather.add(matcher.group(1));
            }

            Pattern links = Pattern.compile("(.+?)<BR/>");
            matcher = links.matcher(desc);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                link = matcher.group(1);
            }

            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                // in = OpenHttpConnection(url1);
                int response = -1;
                URL url = new URL(url1);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
                    throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
                HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConn.connect();
                response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    in = httpConn.getInputStream();
                }
                icon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return Result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            System.out.println("POST EXECUTE");
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
            temp.setText("Temperature: " + temperature);
            condition.setText("Condition: " + condition1);
            date.setText("Date: " + date1);
            humidity.setText("Humidity: " + humidity1);
            wind.setText("Wind: " + wind1);
            icon1.setImageBitmap(icon);
        }
    }

}
```

How may i fix this error:
Error Log :

```
06-05 19:32:11.876: E/Trace(4418): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-05 19:32:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4418): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-05 19:32:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4418): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-05 19:32:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4418):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-05 19:32:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4418):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-05 19:32:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4418):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-05 19:32:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4418):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-05 19:32:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4418):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-05 19:32:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4418):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-05 19:32:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4418):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-05 19:32:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4418):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-05 19:32:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4418):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-05 19:32:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4418): Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; regionStart=1; regionLength=-2
06-05 19:32:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4418):     at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:593)
06-05 19:32:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4418):     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1474)
06-05 19:32:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4418):     at com.gird.completeontologyproject.WeatherSHow$RetriveWeatherTask.doInBackground(WeatherSHow.java:169)
06-05 19:32:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4418):     at com.gird.completeontologyproject.WeatherSHow$RetriveWeatherTask.doInBackground(WeatherSHow.java:1)
06-05 19:32:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4418):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-05 19:32:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4418):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `src.length()` return 1.
Check it before call `String.substring()`

Answer (score 0):

What is length of src? It is too short and that is reason for error.

You should check length before that line, like this:

```
String url1 = "";
if(src.lenth() > 4)
    url1 = src.substring(1, src.length() - 2);
else
    return "";
```

4 is because you start at second character (index 1), and finish substring at second before length of src (minimum 4-2 = 2). You can put other if statement, if you know how substring should look like and how long it should be.

You don't need else, because url1 is already set to "" but you can put some Toast or something else depending on your code.

Comment: and in else condition

Comment: In else you should exit doInBackground because later you are trying to do URL url = new URL(url1); and url1 will be "".

Comment: in else condition, your `url1` variable have value is `""`.

Comment: in else condition url1=src.subString(0.src.length-1);

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a **StringIndexOutOfBoundsException** at `WeatherSHow.java:169`..So as @Zoran suggested please check the length like

```
String url1 = "";
if(src.lenth() > 4)
    url1 = src.substring(1, src.length() - 2);
```

**Also**,You are trying to display too many `Toast` messages in your `doInBackground()` which is creating the problem..You cannot update the UI in `doInBackground()`..do it in your onPostExecute()..

You could wrap the `Toast` in `runOnUIThread()` but this isn't the best solution.
You should set a boolean flag in the catch block when an error occurs, then display an appropriate `Toast` in `onProgressUpdate()`, `onPostExecute()`, or any of the other methods with UI access whenever the flag is true.

Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to know more about Async Task..

Comment: updating ui is doInbackground is wrong but op has `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: when i used this if condition it doesnot show imageview and in else condition.

Comment: That you should decide...becuse without that condition exception would be raised...

Comment: But this code is run properly in another android application

Comment: in else Condition use this way   if(src.lenth() > 4)
    url1 = src.substring(0, src.length() - 1);

Comment: May be it run properly in another android application but in this case, your input data is invalidate. For example your `src` may be set to "a". So let think that can't have `substring(1, src.length() - 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code:

```
String url1 = src.substring(1, src.length() - 2);
```

This code have a problem that is: `Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; regionStart=1; regionLength=-2`. The `src` have only 1 character so when you call `src.length() - 2` return -1.

My solution is you have to check length of `String` before call `substring` method.

Something like that:

```
int length = src.length();
int start = 1;
int end = length - 2;
String  url1 = "";
if(length > start && length < end){
    url1 = src.substring(1, src.length() - 2);
}
```

Hope that help!